# how to show users list in product edit page?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, admin-panel

List all users in product edit page admin panel.
Any tutorial or guide please share.

I just created a tab in product edit page but need to show all users details in that tab.

Here's my code:

```
<?
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Learning\ClothingMaterial\Model\Attribute\Source;

class Material extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Get all options
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {

        $roleName = "merchant";
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$roleModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Authorization\Model\Role');
$userModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\User\Model\User');
$roleModel = $roleModel->load($roleName, 'role_name');
$option_val = [];
        if($roleModel->getId()) {
            $userIds = $roleModel->getRoleUsers();
            foreach($userIds as $userId) {
                $user = $userModel->load($userId);
                $usernames = $user->getUsername();
                $userid = $user->getId();
                $option_val['label'] =  __($userid - $usernames);
                $option_val['value'] =  __($userid.$usernames);
            }
        }
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [$option_val];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which user custmer or admin sub user ?

Comment: all users that created by admin

Comment: which magento version are you using ? do you want to show log in that tab, like which admin user have updated this product ?

Comment: version 2 
i just wanted to show all users in dropdown in product edit page so i can assign product to user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your class and constructor:

```
protected $userFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    ...
}
```

Then create a method in the same class to retrieve the role data:

```
public function getUserData()
{
    $user = $this->userFactory->create();
    echo '<pre>';print_r($user->getData());die;
}
```

You have to get user collection here and use it for dropdown.

Comment: can you please review my code i updated